# populating Grails domain classes

Tags: grails, groovy

I wrote a simple code to populate the Grail domain classes and a code for showing db contents, but it doesn't work. Attached is my code! I appreciate any help.

```
def populateDB(int nofelements)
    {
        def instance
        for (int i=1;i<=nofelements;i++){
            instance=new Avendpoint()
            instance.avName=org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.random(9, true, true)
            instance.bridge=org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.random(9, true, true)
            instance.callerID=org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.random(9, true, true)
            instance.con=false
            instance.state=AvendpointState.ONE_WAY
            instance.uid=org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.random(5, true, true)
            instance.save(flush: true)
        }

        render "The database has been populated successfully!"

    }
    def showDB(){   
        def instance
        String res
        res+=Integer.toString(Avendpoint.count())
        for(int i=1; i<Avendpoint.count(); i++){
        instance=Avendpoint.get(i)
        res+=instance.avName+"<br>"+instance.bridge+"<br>"+instance.callerID+"<br>"+
        instance.con+"<br>"+instance.state+"<br>"+instance.uid+"<br>"
        }
        render res
    }
```

Comment: sigh...what does "It doesn't work" mean?  Is there an error?

Comment: What does it do?  Throw an error?  What version of Grails?  How are you calling `populateDB` -- the usual place is to check for being in development mode in BootStrap.groovy and insert data there if so.  Also, try `instance.save( failOnError:true, flush:true )` as it might be a validation issue?

Comment: No, There is no error, but nothing is in db!

Comment: Are you calling `populateDB`?  Where from?

Comment: Where is the code you posted located? What type of Grails "artifact" is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is try to use: `instance.save(flush: true,failOnError:true)`. By default Grails doesn't throw an exception when domain doesn't it's fields constraints. Maybe instances are rejected while validation and will not be saved.